# Is "extern" C Mandatory under Android - JNI?

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface, extern

After reading a few articles, most of them show how to export C code in Android under JNI. My problem is that I have C++ classes with lots of overloaded functions. If I want to export/wrap them using JNI - Is it possible to do so if I can skip "extern" C which, If I am correct, is used to avoid name mangling of functions.

Comment: @mah Make this an answer, I'd say any of the other tags besides [tag:c] and [tag:c++] are completely irrelevant for the question!

Comment: wikipedia seems to think that JNI doesn't use name mangling. Hence, extern "C" would be required when mixing JNI with C++.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removal of name mangling is required any time C code needs to be able to call into C++ code by symbol. If you're unsure if it's safe to turn that off, you can easily find out: assuming you're starting with code that compiles, remove the `extern "C"` around parts you're interested in. If it still compiles, you're safe... if you're not safe you'll receive undefined reference errors from the linker.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. I guess I have to learn the hard way! Removing extern and testing!

Comment: Right idea, but "compiling" is not a sufficient test.  The poster is working with jni libraries, which is to say dynamic linking performed by name at runtime.  As long as there's no C code (or similar) statically calling the C++, unworkably mangled names will build and and link into a library just fine, but fail at runtime when jni asks the dynamic linker to locate a method by its unmangled name.